# How can I eliminate "UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x00'" in win32com?

Tags: python-3.x, win32com

I'm using the latest version of win32com on Windows 7 and Python 3.6.  `import win32com.client` working fine until recently.  I'm now getting an `UnpicklingError` exception.

I've tried reinstalling the latest version globally as well as in a separate virtual environment.

```
In [1]: import win32com.client
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-acfbed532f32> in <module>()
----> 1 import win32com.client

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py in <module>()
      9 import pythoncom
     10 from . import dynamic
---> 11 from . import gencache
     12 import sys
     13 import pywintypes

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py in <module>()
    658
    659 # Boot up
--> 660 __init__()
    661
    662 def usage():

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py in __init__()
     58         # Initialize the module.  Called once explicitly at module import below
     59         try:
---> 60                 _LoadDicts()
     61         except IOError:
     62                 Rebuild()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py in _LoadDicts()
    111         try:
    112                 p = pickle.Unpickler(f)
--> 113                 version = p.load()
    114                 global clsidToTypelib
    115                 clsidToTypelib = p.load()

UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x00'.
```

Comment: You have a corrupted pickle file in the cache of generated COM interfaces.

Comment: That was the hint I needed.  I just deleted the entire cache and it works fine now.  The cache location on my machine is: C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Temp/gen_py/3.6